# Is there a site for questions related to satellite or its receivers?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site that exists for questions related to satellite or its receivers?

I would like to ask question if a certain satellite receiver will work in a certain country, etc.

Comment: Well, since it's specific to certain country my hunch tells me it fits Travel.SE, but not sure.